# problem putting progressDialog.shide () in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and I am having the following problem.

I am trying to use the progressDialog in in a listview, I make the query to my database, I extract the list and pass it to the listview, I am trying to use the progressDialog so when I start loading the list it will run and tell the user to wait, and when I finish loading the list then the progressDialog is hidden, so far it works for me by bringing me the list and the progressDialog is executed saying to wait, but when I put the progressDialog.hide where the loading of the list ends I this is not accepting that line of code (progressDialog .hidde)

image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt3ab.png)

```
import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:fluterproyecto1/Modulos/DetalleUser.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:progress_dialog/progress_dialog.dart';
    import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    
    String username2 = '';
    String profesion = '';
    String name = '';
    
    class MemberPage extends StatefulWidget {
      MemberPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _MemberPageState createState() => _MemberPageState();
    }
    
    class _MemberPageState extends State<MemberPage> {
      Map data;
      List userData;
      ProgressDialog progressDialog;
      String name = '';
    
      Future getData() async {
        http.Response response =
            await http.get("http://masciudad.com.co/flutter/getdata.php");
        data = json.decode(response.body);
        //setState(() {
        //progressDialog.show();
        userData = data["data"];
        //progressDialog.hide();
        //});
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        getData();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog(context, type: ProgressDialogType.Normal);
        progressDialog.style(message: 'Por favor espere...');
        progressDialog.show();
     
        setState(() {
          obtenerPreferencias();
        });
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Bienvenido $username2"),
          ),
          body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: userData == null ? 0 : userData.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return InkWell(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset(
                        "assets/128.jpg",
                        width: 30.0,
                        height: 30.0,
                      ),
                      //CircleAvatar(
                      ///cuando la imagen es de interntet
                      //backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      //  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/follettkyle/128.jpg"),
                      //),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "${userData[index]["username"]} - ${userData[index]["profesion"]}",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                            new DetalleUser(name: userData[index]["username"]))),
              );
            },
          ),
    
          //Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          //  builder: (BuildContext context) => MyHomePage()));
          //Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/MyHomePage");
        );
      }
    
      
    
      Future obtenerPreferencias() async {
        SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        setState(() {
          username2 = preferences.get("username2") ?? "";
          profesion = preferences.get("profesion") ?? "";
        });
      }
    
      Future destruirPreferencias() async {
        SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        preferences.clear();
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: What does it mean "Is not accepting"? Do you get an error?

Comment: I don't really know where to put progressDialog.hide (); inside Widget build (BuildContext context) because it marks me error or tells me to remove it

Comment: attach image at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `addPostFrameCallback` and put logical in another function `getRelatedData()`

code snippet

```
 void getRelatedData() async {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog(context, type: ProgressDialogType.Normal);
    progressDialog.style(message: 'Por favor espere...');
    progressDialog.show();
    await getData();
    await obtenerPreferencias();
    progressDialog.hide();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getRelatedData();
    });
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:progress_dialog/progress_dialog.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

String username2 = '';
String profesion = '';
String name = '';

class MemberPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MemberPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MemberPageState createState() => _MemberPageState();
}

class _MemberPageState extends State<MemberPage> {
  Map data;
  List userData;
  ProgressDialog progressDialog;
  String name = '';

  Future getData() async {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get("http://masciudad.com.co/flutter/getdata.php");
    data = json.decode(response.body);
    //setState(() {
    //progressDialog.show();
    userData = data["data"];
    print("getData Done");
    //progressDialog.hide();
    //});
  }

  void getRelatedData() async {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog(context, type: ProgressDialogType.Normal);
    progressDialog.style(message: 'Por favor espere...');
    progressDialog.show();
    await getData();
    await obtenerPreferencias();
    progressDialog.hide();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getRelatedData();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Bienvenido $username2"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: userData == null ? 0 : userData.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return InkWell(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.network(
                      "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9",
                      width: 30.0,
                      height: 30.0,
                    ),
                    //CircleAvatar(
                    ///cuando la imagen es de interntet
                    //backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    //  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/follettkyle/128.jpg"),
                    //),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "${userData[index]["username"]} - ${userData[index]["profesion"]}",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                /*Navigator.push(
                context,
                new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                    new DetalleUser(name: userData[index]["username"])));*/
              });
        },
      ),

      //Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      //  builder: (BuildContext context) => MyHomePage()));
      //Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/MyHomePage");
    );
  }

  Future obtenerPreferencias() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      username2 = preferences.get("username2") ?? "";
      profesion = preferences.get("profesion") ?? "";
    });
  }

  Future destruirPreferencias() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    preferences.clear();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MemberPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear @Yeimer I would suggest read documentation carefully

https://pub.dev/packages/progress_dialog

Add the Package this

```
dependencies:
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.4
```

**1**
Initialize your ProgressDialog object

```
final ProgressDialog prDialog = ProgressDialog(context);
//For normal dialog
prDialog = ProgressDialog(context,type: ProgressDialogType.Normal, isDismissible: true/false, showLogs: true/false);
```

**2** Showing the progress dialog

```
await pr.show();
```

**3**
Dismissing the progress dialog

```
prDialog.hide().then((isHidden) {
  print(isHidden);
});

// or simply
await prDialog.hide();
```